# NCover installation

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, ncover, ncover-explorer

I'm installing NCover Complete trial version, and wondered if it's possible to install to a different folder and have NCover as part of the VCS?  Otherwise the current version of NCover (v3.3.2) would be shared amongst all projects and I can invisage problems when upgrading NCover.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the installation directory from the installer, but as the program doesn't depend on registry settings, you can copy the installed assemblies to a folder in your VCS and run from there. As long as you remember to run "regsvr32 NCover.Lib.x86.dll"* from an administrative command prompt on the new location of said file, Ncover should work great.

NCover support is usually pretty good about helping with config and install issue, BTW FYI.

- NCover.Lib.x64.dll for x64 systems that need to cover x64 code